# How to init db for tortoise-orm in sanic app?

Tags: python-3.7, sanic, tortoise-orm

Is there a way to register databases in [tortoise-orm](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) from my Sanic app other than calling `Tortoise.init`?

```
from tortoise import Tortoise

await Tortoise.init(
        db_url='sqlite://db.sqlite3',
        modules={'models': ['app.models']}
    )
    # Generate the schema
    await Tortoise.generate_schemas()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `register_tortoise` available from `tortoise.contrib.sanic`

It registers `before_server_start` and `after_server_stop` hooks to set-up and tear-down Tortoise-ORM inside a Sanic webserver. Check out this sanic integration [example](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/tree/develop/examples/sanic) from tortoise orm.

you can use it like,

```
from sanic import Sanic, response

from models import Users
from tortoise.contrib.sanic import register_tortoise

app = Sanic(__name__)


@app.route("/")
async def list_all(request):
    users = await Users.all()
    return response.json({"users": [str(user) for user in users]})

register_tortoise(
    app, db_url="sqlite://:memory:", modules={"models": ["models"]}, generate_schemas=True
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

models.py

```
from tortoise import Model, fields


class Users(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.CharField(50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"User {self.id}: {self.name}"
```

Comment: register_tortoise works when I connect my Sanic app to PostgreSQL on GCP's Cloud SQL to create tables from my models but when the app is deployed to Cloud Run, it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Sanic maintainer here.

Another answer offers the suggestion of using `tortoise.contrib.sanic.register_tortoise` that uses `before_server_start` and `after_server_stop` listeners.

I want to add a caveat to that. If you are using Sanic in ASGI mode, then you really should be using the other listeners: `after_server_start` and `before_server_stop`.

This is because there is not really a "before" server starting or "after" server stopping when the server is outside of Sanic. Therefore, if you are implementing the suggested solution as adopted by `tortoise` in ASGI mode, you will receive warnings in your logs every time you spin up a server. It is still supported, but it might be an annoyance.

In such case:

```py
@app.listener('after_server_start')
async def setup_db(app, loop):
    ...

@app.listener('before_server_stop')
async def close_db(app, loop):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for this, when running via gunicorn sanic worker, register_tortoise usage is correct?

Comment: Yes. The gunicorn worker is a subclass of gunicorn itself. So, that should be fine.